# Multiple forms on one page causes validation conflict due to required attribute

Tags: jquery, validation

I have two forms on a page: `register` and `sign-in`.

The register form is simple and has some fields that have a required attribute e.g.

```
<form name="register" id="register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="forename" required />
  .... many more fields here ...
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>

<form name="sign-in" id="sign-in" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="username" required />
  <input type="password" name="password" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
</form>
```

The `sign-in` form just needs your username and password. But the problem is that when I click the submit button to sign-in, I get a validation error coming from the `register` form asking my to put in my forename. But I don't want to register! I just want to sign-in. Why is the submission of the sign-in form causing the register form to check validation?

How can I fix this so they the forms behave entirely independently? I have using JQuery form validation and have a common validator that applies to all forms binded like this:

```
$('form').validate({
// common validation rules in here
)}
```

From the comments I can see that this is the issue. But how to resolve it and still have a common validation function for all forms on the site?

Comment: are you binding the validation handler to $('form')?  if so, try adding a unique id to each form, and selecting via the id.  Also make sure your </form> tags are in the right place

Comment: @circusdei yes I binded the validation handler to $('form') and put error messages for all common form elements in there. `$('form').validate({` Otherwise I have to create a duplicate set of validation rules for each form that uses the same fields. Is this wrong?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: why is `register` in a `form` if there is no `submit` input option?

Comment: Have you tried running the page through a validator?  I'm thinking there's some HTML out of place.

Comment: I removed my answer. Each of your forms should have their own .validate() function as @circusdei mentions above. Just because the field is the same in two forms it exists in two seperate-unrelated places and the validation for each should not be shared (i.e. validation should be done on a per form basis).

Comment: @circusdei the HTML on the page is all ok

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to each form tag:

```
<form id="form1">

</form>
<form id="form2">

</form>
```

And loop through each from individually with jQuery:

```
$('form').each(function(){ ... generic validation for all forms here ... });
```